# 7 segment OCR using Google Cloud Vision

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision with TEXT_DETECTION to try and do OCR on a seven segment display, but am getting pretty lousy results, mostly because it seems to think its a different language. The typical locale it seems to associate it with is "zh" or "ja".

Is there a specific hint that I can give Cloud Vision which might produce better results?

For example, this image below --
[image]

produces this output --

```
"locale" : "ja",
...
...
"description" : "ココ\n"
```

I have also tried to preprocess the image by increasing contrast, gaussian blur and even erode it to fill in the spaces between the segments, but without much luck.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have checked the EXIF orientation?
I think that GoogleCloudVisionAPI's source field ignore the EXIF information.
Let's rotate this image so as to be correctly showed without EXIF information.

Comment: maybe go ahead and try performing some image processing and then removing the background noise, then push to image for processing on Google Cloud Vision for OCR. That should do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps you could try dilating the image so the segments join up before running OCR.  This would be a case where LESS resolution might actually produce a better result (maybe).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in your json code:

```
"languageHints": ["en"]
```